# A Redstone circuit that will only fire if a specific input is turned on?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I've been working on this for a a while, and can't figure it out. Is there a logic circuit that will only be on if one of the two inputs is on, but a specific input?

So if A is the input I want to focus on, if A is on and B is off, then the output is on. Otherwise, the output is off. If it helps, I am trying to make prisoner's dilemma.

Comment: Could you please return the question to it's previous state and add the solution as an answer? I, for example, couldn't figure out how to do this, and some others too. It would help future visitors - 90% of Arqade's trafic is from Google.

Comment: I put it back and said how I did it

Comment: Is (A and not B) the only input you want that results in the output being on?

Comment: Yes, that's the only thing that I want the output to be on for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, just put a piston connected to B that would interrupt a when B was on, and had A lead to the output. Here is how to make it:

[image: Redstone circuit as described above]

Answer (score 3):

Place 3 blocks in a row. On the leftmost block, put a lever on the side facing you, and a redstone torch on top. On the other two blocks, place redstone on top and a lever on the rightmost block, again on the side facing you. On the other side, place a torch facing away on the middle block, which will be your output.
[image: The lamps are aesthetics, not necessary.]

Comment: By the way this circuit takes up to 2 ticks, or .2 seconds.

Comment: Also, if you want it to turn on when only B is on, just reverse it horizontally, or just relabel it so that B is on the left.